# java: executing a Object in new JVM instance and getting the results

Tags: java, jvm, instance

I have a third party jar that connects to a server and executes command and returns result.
But this jar connects to only one server in a single instance of JVM.

So how can i execute a Object of a class in a new JVM instance get the results/ exception  back in invoker JVM instance.

Comment: That depends on what the library does and how it does it.  This can be done any number of way, without knowing the library its impossible to say.  I suggest you ask whoever provided you with the library and supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reflection get to at any non-final state to change the server. Class instances are unique per classloader, so you could load the third-party class in a new custom classloader for each server to connect to.

http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20custom%20classloader

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reverse-engineer the protocol between the client lib and the server. tcpmon might help you. A debugger might help you. A profiler might help you as you can see what sort of methods get called.